Centripetal Force A Level Physics. Can someone explain the answer to me please?

At Z why is the tension component greater than the weight? and why is it the opposite at X? I know the Centripetal force acts towards the centre, and i understand why they are added and subtracted at each point but their magnitude confuses me.

do you know how to add vectors?

yes i do know how to add vectors

Draw the vectors representing the forces acting on the mass at points $X$ and $Z$. The answer will immediately become clear then.

oh so the centripetal force vector is equal to the weight and tension vector connected head to tail?

No, the centripetal force and the weight always have the same magnitude, but will point in different directions depending on the position. The tension is the sum of those vectors.

actually, that's incorrect. tension is not a vector at all, but the magnitude of the component of the total force which points along the string.

ah  thanks for your clarification, though im still a bit confused. could you draw a vector diagram for each point? and also if tension is a force why isn't it a vector? thanks

this may be one of the worst problems, ever. Please cite source for garbage like this. The reason the tension at X is less than the weight is because the problem states that it is. It is a stipulated fact. How that can be, is a limit on the speed of rotation. What is or what isn't "the centripetal force" is frame dependent, and there is no frame specified in which to do the analysis. idk, it seems like these people are just trying to confuse students, or are making assumption where they should not be made, if you want to understand physics in arbitrary reference frames.

Its because we know that the object is still in circular motion at the point Z. This means that there should be a net centripetal force towards the center of the circle of magnitude mv^2/r.
It is at point Z where the centripetal force and gravity are exactly facing opposite to each other.
Thus, tension should overcome this gravitation force (which is opposing the most now) and still should produce the centripetal force.
Therefore, tension has to be maximum here.
Similarly, you can see how tension would be minimum at point X (where gravity is supporting instead of opposing).

oh ok i see now thank you! so tension is changing size at each point? and at Y would it be an in-between of Z and X?

Yes! It varies from point to point.
